# How can I use html5 cache manifest with CakePHP?

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cache-manifest

I want to use the html5 cache manifest technology with CakePHP,
but I don't know where to place the cache manifest in CakePHP,
I've searched for a solution, but I do not found anything.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest way to access one manifest file in all views is to look at your layouts, for example

```
View/Layouts/default.ctp
```

and replace `<html>` with

```
<?php echo "<html manifest='".$this->webroot."manifest.php'>"; ?>
```

in which manifest.php is located in

```
app/webroot/manifest.php
```

and looks something like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/cache-manifest');
    echo "CACHE MANIFEST\n";
    echo "\n\nNETWORK:\n";
    echo "*\n";

    echo "\n\nCACHE:\n"; 

    echo "# Version: 1\n";
?>
```

So the manifest.php is only needed once and can be used for all views.

**HINT:**
For a dynamic manifest-file you can use a code snippet from here:
http://nial.me/2010/01/using-the-html5-cache-manifest-with-dynamic-files/

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution, putting the manifest in default.ctp, but it causes some problems, all my pages was cached... i think it's discribed in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html) "...the page that referenced the manifest is automatically cached even if it isn't explicitly mentioned".

...couse this all my pages was being cached, manifest is checked in each page. And when another user logs in they see the last user homepage and other pages.

The final solution: create a redirect/loading page

**1 - create the redirect page:**
I had create the Pages/redirect.ctp file and the function redirect(){} in the Pages controller. A simple page, just with a hello message and a loading bar based on the applicationCache progress event:

> var appCache = window.applicationCache;
>   appCache.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
>     console.log(event.loaded + " of " + event.total + " files...");
>     //make some changes in the page' loading bar
>   }, false);

**2 - Load manifest only in the redirect page:**
In the View/Layouts/default.ctp I filtered the  tag to show the manifest only in the redirect page:

> <? if($this->request->params['controller']=='pages' && 
>   $this->request->params['action']=='redirect'):  ?>
> <html
>   manifest="<?=$this->webroot?>manifest.php"> 
>  
>   <? else: ?>
>   <html >
>   <?
>   endif; ?>

**3 - Use the redirect page in the auth component to lead my user 

to redirect page after login:**
In the appController a setted auth component like this

> public $components = array (
>   
>   'Session',
>   
>       'Auth' => array (
>   
>           'authError' => "user or password invalid",
>   
>           'unauthorizedRedirect' => "/pages/redirect?err=login",
>   
>           'loginRedirect' => "/pages/redirect",
>   
>           'logoutRedirect' => "/",
>   
>           'loginAction' => "/user/login",
>   
>           'authorize' => array ('Controller') 
>   
>       ) 
>   
>     );

now only the elements putted in the manifest will be cached. The redirect page is cached (according the spec) but the applicationCache event updates the page torning this "dinamic".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the manifest file it should go into /app/webroot, the directory that your vhost should also use for the site. besides this there is nothing really related to CakePHP with this.

Have a look at this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Ok I know what is the application cache.
What I'm trying to find is how to use the manifest file foreach view on the CakePHP application. 
But if I've to place it into the /app/webroot, it is a one manifest file for alle the CakePHP application.

Comment: Read the link I've provided. There is no limit in cache files. When Cake is generating the pages it will always render a layout file which will have the html tag except it is not a html view/layout you render. Simply set a default manifest file up there, something like if (!isset($cacheManifist)) { echo 'default.mf'; } else { echo $cacheManifest; Set the var from within any view file.